# c# cast multi column listbox back to struct

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a multi column listbox, which gets filled with structs:

```cs
List<SoftwareAssetStruct> software = new List<SoftwareAssetStruct>();
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
{
    software.Add(new SoftwareAssetStruct()
    {
        Softwareid = dataRow["id"].ToString(),
        Softwarename = dataRow["software_name"].ToString(),
        Softwareversion = dataRow["software_version"].ToString(),
        Softwaregroup = dataRow["software_group"].ToString(),
        Softwarelicensenr = dataRow["software_license_nr"].ToString()
    });

}

softListBox.ItemsSource = software;
softListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
```

After the selection is done, I navigate to a new Page.

```cs
private void SelectSoftware(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    NavigationService.Navigate(new MailPage(softListBox)); 
}
```

Now I´m able to visualize those entries, but I´m not able to cast the back to a struct so I can access the separate Data-Fields

```cs
public MailPage(ListBox lbx)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Array komisch;

    if (lbx != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lbx.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            softListBox12.Items.Add(lbx.SelectedItems[i]);

        }
    }

    foreach( SoftwareAssetStruct structAsset in softListBox12.Items)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(structAsset.Softwarename);

    }
}
```

I have defined such structs on both pages:

```cs
private class SoftwareAssetStruct
{
    public string Softwareid { get; set; }

    public string Softwarename { get; set; }

    public string Softwareversion { get; set; }

    public string Softwaregroup { get; set; }

    public string Softwarelicensenr { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to Cast it back I get this Error Message:

> System.InvalidCastException: "[A]SoftwareAssetStruct cannot be cast to [B]SoftwareAssetStruct. Type A originates from 'Share-Me, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\Share-Me\Share-Me\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Share-Me.dll'. Type B originates from 'Share-Me, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\Share-Me\Share-Me\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Share-Me.dll'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have defined such structs on both pages

This shouldn't be done. What you have now are two completely different classes (from the compiler standpoint). Use only one class and add appropriate references to it on your pages if necessary.